# How to get attributes from child elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-selectors, parent-child

How to get attributes from child elements but not get attribute from parent element inside container?
I want parent attributes not to be displayed in the code, I tried with:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call (document.getElementById ("container"). GetElementsByClassName ("wp-activ").querySelectorAll('*'))
```

but it doesn't work....

This is my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="parent"  name="parentone" > 
        <div id="childone" style="height:10px">
            <div id="childtwo" style="background-color:red">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent" name="parenttwo" >
        <div id="childthree" style="height:10px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent" name="parentthree" >
        <div id="childfour" style="height:10px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

```
function myFunction() {

  var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll('*'));
  // Loop over the array
  var results = "";

  var attri = "";
  divs.forEach(function(div){
        attri += div.getAttribute("style");

  });

    results = attri;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results ;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) lets you use complicated selectors to find all elements that match a criteria. You can use `document.querySelectorAll('#container .parent *')` to find all elements under `.parent` which is under `#container` without getting the parents themselves.

**Note:** the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) collection produced by `Document.querySelectorAll()` has a native [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method, so you don't need to convert it to an array. If you do want to convert it to an array anyway, use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var results = [];
  
  document.querySelectorAll('#container .parent *')
    .forEach(function(div) {
      results.push(div.getAttribute("style"));
    });


  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results.join(', ');

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="parent" name="parentone">
    <div id="childone" style="height:10px">
      <div id="childtwo" style="background-color:red">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent" name="parenttwo">
    <div id="childthree" style="height:10px"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent" name="parentthree">
    <div id="childfour" style="height:10px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```